# Directive is not loading and no error is shown

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-bootstrap

I have fork from the Tabs on ui-bootstrap library, and another directive that transform the Tab directive also I have another module that is interpreted as a second app on my main application, but when I tied the both directives to the second module nothing renders, if I go back to the main app and inject those there everything works fine, so any idea why I'm not getting error when the directives is injected on the second module, I want to do this because of the module pattern and separating concerns.

Why I'm not getting any error?

**UPDATE**
Thanks to Jugnu's answer what solves the problem of separating two modules and loading them manually:

```js
//this is your module1 functionality
var module1 = angular.module('module1', []);
module1.directive('module1Directive', function() {
  return {
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      element.bind('click', function() {
        alert('Im module1')
      });
    }
  }
});

module1.controller('Module1Ctrl', ['$scope',
  function($scope) {
    $scope.lable = 'module 1';
  }
]);

//this is your module2 functionality
var module2 = angular.module('module2', []);
module2.directive('module2Directive', function() {
  return {
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      element.bind('click', function() {
        alert('Im module2')
      });
    }
  }
});

module2.controller('Module2Ctrl', ['$scope',
  function($scope) {
    $scope.lable = 'module 2';
  }
]);


window.onload = function() {
  //remove ng-app and bootstrap your app manully
  angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById('module1'), ['module1', 'module2']);
  angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById('module2'), ['module1', 'module2']);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div id="module1" ng-controller="Module1Ctrl">
  <label>{{lable}}</label>
  <div>
    <button module1-directive>Module1 directive</button>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button module2-directive>Module2 directive</button>
  </div>
</div>
<hr>
<div id="module2" ng-controller="Module2Ctrl">
  <label>{{lable}}</label>
  <div>
    <button module1-directive>Module1 directive</button>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button module2-directive>Module2 directive</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: are you injecting your second module as dependency in your first (main)module?

Comment: Should I ? because I want to be two different modules(apps) with no relation between them.

Comment: if you will not inject module where your directive is defined then how will your main module will get directive dependencies?

Comment: I can do this with ng-module, right? As far as I understand I can register a module with that directive.

Comment: here is demo : http://jsfiddle.net/jugnu_pathak/8uac3vy2/1/

Comment: yes, I got that, but I want something like this: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L2y4yv16/2/)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jugnu_pathak/8uac3vy2/2/ look at this

Comment: yes! that's it, works for me, thanks!